# Get epoch time with decimals from a PHP DateTime object?

Tags: php, datetime

```
$d = new \DateTime("2016-02-25 19:14:10.080415");

echo floatval($d->getTimestamp() . $d->format(".u")), "\n";  // 1456424050.0804
```

This works, but feels very akward. Is there any better way to get a floating point number of seconds from a `DateTime` object? I'm looking for the same value that `microtime(true)` would return for the current time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is an easier way

```
echo $d->format('U.u');
```

Comment: I can't believe I missed that. Thanks, will mark as answer as soon as SO lets me.